# MVC 5 how to share one page to another

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I create model "Leave Page" and create Controller

```
namespace technotime.Models
{
    public class Leavepage
    {
        [Key]
        public int LeavepageID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("fempid")]
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public EmployeeRegistration fempid { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "End Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Reason For Leave")]
        public string ReasonForLeave { get; set; }

        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        [Display(Name = "Discription")]
        public string Discription { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Status")]
        public Boolean Status { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
namespace technotime.Controllers
{
    public class LeavepagesController : Controller
    {
        private ApplicationDbContext db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        // GET: Leavepages
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var leavepages = db.Leavepages.Include(l => l.fempid);
            return View(leavepages.ToList());
        }

        // GET: Leavepages/Details/5
        public ActionResult Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Leavepage leavepage = db.Leavepages.Find(id);
            if (leavepage == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(leavepage);
        }

        // GET: Leavepages/Create
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            ViewBag.EmpID = new SelectList(db.EmployeeRegistrations, "EmpId", "FirstName");
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Leavepages/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "LeavepageID,EmpID,StartDate,EndDate,ReasonForLeave,Discription,Status")] Leavepage leavepage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Leavepages.Add(leavepage);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }

            ViewBag.EmpID = new SelectList(db.EmployeeRegistrations, "EmpId", "FirstName", leavepage.EmpID);
            return View(leavepage);
        }

        // GET: Leavepages/Edit/5
        public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Leavepage leavepage = db.Leavepages.Find(id);
            if (leavepage == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            ViewBag.EmpID = new SelectList(db.EmployeeRegistrations, "EmpId", "FirstName", leavepage.EmpID);
            return View(leavepage);
        }

        // POST: Leavepages/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "LeavepageID,EmpID,StartDate,EndDate,ReasonForLeave,Discription,Status")] Leavepage leavepage)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(leavepage).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ViewBag.EmpID = new SelectList(db.EmployeeRegistrations, "EmpId", "FirstName", leavepage.EmpID);
            return View(leavepage);
        }

        // GET: Leavepages/Delete/5
        public ActionResult Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Leavepage leavepage = db.Leavepages.Find(id);
            if (leavepage == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(leavepage);
        }

        // POST: Leavepages/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Leavepage leavepage = db.Leavepages.Find(id);
            db.Leavepages.Remove(leavepage);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

how can i share one database to another database?

Comment: can you please explain your problem statement in more details ?

Comment: I think you can simply pass view and model. or as prtialView. Explain a bit more...

Comment: partial view... ok

Comment: din't work. i explain you brif

Comment: 1. I Create Leavepage Module  & Controller  Leavepage in MVC5
Code As shown in below:
namespace technotime.Models
{
    public class Leavepage
    { 
        [Key]
        public int LeavepageID { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("fempid")]

        [Display(Name = "Employee Name")]
        public int EmpID { get; set; }
        public EmployeeRegistration fempid { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Start Date")]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }
And Create Leavepages

Comment: Controller In MVC5 and i want to show this page into registration page

Comment: how do i link this leavepage in the registraion page